# Page background in frame not working

Tags: xaml, mobile, uwp

I have main page:

```
 <Page   >
    <Grid>
        <SplitView PaneBackground="Transparent"  x:Name="mySplitView" DisplayMode="Overlay"  IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsOpenMenu, Mode=TwoWay}"   OpenPaneLength="320">
            <SplitView.Pane>
               ...
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Frame x:Name="frame"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                            <TransitionCollection>
                                <NavigationThemeTransition>
                                    <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                                        <EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo/>
                                    </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                                </NavigationThemeTransition>
                            </TransitionCollection>
                        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
                    </Frame>                   
                </Grid>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>          

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In Frame i load other page. Example Page1.
In Page1 set background:

```
<Page   Background="Red" >
</Page>
```

And this not working? Background is not Red. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your second `Page` needs content. Try this:

```
<Page Background="Red">
    <Grid/>
</Page>
```

Typically for `Page`s and `UserControl`s, you would actually set the `Background` of the content root element instead of the element itself:

```
<Page>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**EDIT**

I ran the app in the mobile emulator instead of the local machine and can reproduce your issue. All I can suggest is that you set the background on the content root element instead of the page, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Is the background of the content element of your second page set? It could be overriding the page's background.

Comment: No... Set only on page. Example <Page Background="Red">
    <Grid/>
</Page>

Comment: I can't reproduce it, the background works for me. Given exactly the code that you have provided, the background of `Page1` inside `frame` appears red. Is there more code?

Comment: i have added example

Comment: I reproduced your issue by running it in the mobile emulator instead of the local machine. It appears to only affect the mobile OS instead of the desktop OS. See my edit.

Comment: I see. I did it how you say. Thx.